# ARKIT image detection crash when AR Resource Images have "warnings"

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, image-recognition

Using XCODE 9.4.1, I am playing around with ARKIT's image recognition in my app, and when I add an image resource that has no warnings it works absolutely fine.

But when I add an image that has warnings (as per attached image):

[image]

it crashes immediately (11db) once the ARSCNView is loaded (the device camera does not even "switch on"), with the error :

com.apple.arkit.technique.imageDetection (15): signal SIGABRT

[image]

I saw in other threads that adding images with "yellow" warnings will have mediocre tracking but will NOT result in a crash (it's a warning after all).

Adding "warning-free" AR Resource images is not a work-around for me as the images I am obliged to use cannot make those warnings disappear, and have to compromise with the suboptimal tracking.

To confirm, everything works fine when I have only warning-free images in the AR Resources folder.

Is it some bug, or does anyone know how to fix this? Appreciate any help

Comment: I'd recommend [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) and attaching the offending image.

Comment: Thanks @rickster, I will - fwiw the crash actually occurs on any image (or several images) with warnings, ie not only a specific image

Comment: Have filed a bug report with Apple, as the crash always happens, even after testing it in a brand new project with the minimal Apple code for image recognition. my debugger's last line is :

src_frame.image.width * output_frame_height_)) < max_slack

in case it's relevant. Any workaround solutions in the meantime are welcome!